# How to pass two parameters into function or none in typescript?

Tags: typescript, parameters, parameter-passing

I wanted to improve a function that just returns a status. It does not accept any other parameters except a logger and a message to log with it.

```
export function status(logger: Logger, reason: string) {
  logger.info(reason);
  return {
    result: 'ok'
  };
}
```

However I want to make the parameters optional so if I don't want to log anything, I don't need to pass anything. Thus I changed it like this:

```
export function status(logger?: Logger, reason?: string) {
  reason && logger?.info(reason);
  return {
    result: 'ok'
  };
}
```

However I can still provide a logger but not provide a reason and I don't like that. I want this function to accept either both or no parameters. So I tried something like this:

```
export function status(param: {logger: Logger, reason: string} | {} = {}) {
  param?.logger.info(reason);
  return {
    result: 'ok'
  };
}
```

However now I am getting `TS2339: Property 'logger' does not exist on type '{} | { logger: Logger; reason: string; }'.   Property 'logger' does not exist on type '{}'.` and I do not know how to do this correctly. I would want to learn - can you please explain how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why not use overloading?

Comment: Make the param itself optional and remove the `| {}` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You dont provide how the type Logger looks like. But seeing your code, I assume it must be something similar to this:

```
type Logger = { info: (someInfo: string) => void }
```

Define the type of the params that the status function receives:

```
type paramsStatus = {
  logger: { info: (someInfo: string) => void },
  reason: string,
}
```

You make params optional with ? operator. Since logger and reason are mandatory (see the type above), they both have to be passed to the status function. Both or neither of them, both ways are correct.

```
export function status(params?: paramsStatus) {
  params && params.logger.info(params.reason); //If params exist, then log the info
  return {
    result: 'ok',
  };
}
```